# Pass state from parent for toggling multiple children elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, popover

I'm trying to toggle multiple popovers with useState true/false, which was working fine within its own component. However, I now need for the state to be set from inside the parent component, so that it can be passed to another sibling component, but doing this sets the state of each popover to be all the same, so they now all open at once. How can I separate each one with its own individual state?

Here's the popover component (using react-tiny-popover library):

```
export default function Marker({ isPopoverOpen, setIsPopoverOpen }) {
  return (
    <Popover
      isOpen={isPopoverOpen}
      content={<div>Popover content</div>}
    >
      <button onClick={() => setIsPopoverOpen(!isPopoverOpen)}>
        Toggle popover
      </button>
    </Popover>
  );
}
```

and I'm setting it in the parent component like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isPopoverOpen, setIsPopoverOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: By creating a state for each item you need state for. What that **looks** like depends on what you actually need, for example, it could be an object/map of UIDs to popover state.

Comment: @DaveNewton There's at least 30 of these popovers though, so not sure what the syntax would look like to create a state for each of them?

Comment: If they're uniquely identifiable it could be as simple as an object of UID => popover state; the syntax is that of an object.